# Protect Sheets while allowing user to access some formatting functionality

Tags: vba, excel

Have the following code at the Workbook object level, but it's not allowing for the autofilter or ungrouping of columns.

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    For Each ws In Sheets
        With ws
            .Protect Password:="xxxxxxxx", Userinterfaceonly:=True,      
            AllowFormattingColumns:=True, AllowFormattingRows:=True, _
            AllowFiltering:=True, AllowInsertingRows:=True,   
            AllowSorting:=True, AllowDeletingRows:=True
        End With

Next ws
End Sub
```

Comment: Would it matter if there are other WorkSheet Macros that contain protect/unprotect commands within them?  Are they conflicting somehow?

Comment: Try adding `.EnableOutlining = True`

Comment: @Shrewd1 If the sheet is already protected, you would need to unprotect it first, with any password it may have.

Comment: Adding ".EnableOutlining = True" worked Demetri!

Comment: Not able to use AutoFilters still?